# Resize window but maintain zoom level

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working with three.js and getting the hang of how the camera and rendered work. Currently I am building out the ability to drag and resize the canvas that three.js draws too.

i want to be able to drag and resize the canvas, without the scene getting larger. So a larger canvas displays more of the scene, not a bigger scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still looking for a solution, here is a fiddle doing what you are trying to achieve : http://jsfiddle.net/psyrendust/8nbpehj3/ (I do not own this fiddle)

You need to play with the field of view:

```
// remember these initial values
var tanFOV = Math.tan( ( ( Math.PI / 180 ) * camera.fov / 2 ) );
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

// Event Listeners
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize( event ) {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    // adjust the FOV
    camera.fov = ( 360 / Math.PI ) * Math.atan( tanFOV * ( window.innerHeight / windowHeight ) );

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Hope this helps.